# loading data from server giving SIGBART

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, image

I am loading images and links from my server in imageview as banners, the backend I'm using is laravel, images are indexed by numbers, every banner has an image number which will show the full image link using that number

```
var url: [URL?] = []
    var image: [URL?] = []
    var idx = 0

func getJSONBottom() {
        let params = [
            "position":"bottom"
        ]
        self.getJSON(url: "/public/api/ads", params: params) { (response: [Any?]) in
            response.forEach({ (res) in
                if let res = res as? [String:Any?] {
                    let imageString = res["image"] as! String ** error in this line Thread 1: signal SIGABRT ***
                    let imageURL = URL(string: imageString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!)
                    print("resources: \(res)")
                    self.image.append(imageURL)
                    if let urlString = res["url"] as? String {
                        self.url.append(URL(string: urlString))
                    }
                }
                
                self.initAds(idx: self.idx)
                self.initTime()
            })
        }
    }
    
    func getJSON(url: String, params: [String:String], success: @escaping ([Any?]) -> ()) {
        let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager(baseURL: URL(string: "http://mysite.co"))
        manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
        manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
        
        manager.get(url, parameters: params, progress: { (_) in
            
        }, success: { (_, response: Any?) in
            if let res = response as? [Any?] {
                success(res)
            }
        }) { (_, error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

here is the banner load functions, I am using int to index the images and from there I get the image full link by its number, here is the full code so it will be clear for you

```
  @objc func tapBottomAds() {
        if idx < self.url.count, let url = self.url[idx] {
            self.tapAds(url: url)
        }
    }
    
    func tapAds(url: URL?) {
        if let url = url, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let view = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WebAdsViewController") as! WebAdsViewController
            view.url = url
            let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: view)
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func initTime() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(changeAds), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func changeAds() {
        self.idx += 1
        if self.idx >= self.url.count {
            self.idx = 0
        }
        
        initAds(idx: self.idx)
    }
    
    func initAds(idx: Int) {
        if idx < self.image.count, let imageURL = self.image[idx] {
            self.ads.sd_setImage(with: imageURL, completed: nil)
        }
    }
```

the console error

```
-24 21:27:38.026738+0300 QHarajApp[94799:17515479] VERBOSE: getNotificationTypes:mSubscriptionStatus: -15
2021-02-24 21:27:38.026852+0300 QHarajApp[94799:17515479] VERBOSE: getNotificationTypes:mSubscriptionStatus: -15
2021-02-24 21:27:38.027036+0300 QHarajApp[94799:17515479] VERBOSE: updateInAppMessagesFromOnSession
2021-02-24 21:27:38.027590+0300 QHarajApp[94799:17515479] VERBOSE: resetRedisplayMessagesBySession with redisplayedInAppMessages: {
}
2021-02-24 21:27:38.027722+0300 QHarajApp[94799:17515479] VERBOSE: Evaluating in app messages
2021-02-24 21:27:38.058969+0300 QHarajApp[94799:17515685] VERBOSE: network response (OSRequestUpdateNotificationTypes): {
    success = 1;
}
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x7fff86d79440) to 'NSString' (0x7fff86d9fbb0).
2021-02-24 21:27:38.222991+0300 QHarajApp[94799:17515479] Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x7fff86d79440) to 'NSString' (0x7fff86d9fbb0).
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x7fff86d79440) to 'NSString' (0x7fff86d9fbb0).
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro (38BEB013-0D7E-4398-B49A-0C118BCA1A20) - Runtime: iOS 14.4 (18D46) - DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro
(lldb)
```

Comment: Clearly not all "resoruces" have images, or their images aren't `Strings`

Comment: When you post a question about a crash, indicate which line is crashing, and include the complete error message you are getting.

Comment: line is mentioned in the question

Comment: Post the rest of the error. Signal SIGBRT always contains the reason of the issue.

Comment: This crash `let imageString = res["image"] as! String`? Which a message in console? What could be wrong here? First the `as! String` is yelling: I'll crash if the thing before is not a `String`. So, if `res["image"]` is `nil`, or is not a `String` (an `Int` for instance). But that's guessing. Error message in console + showing `res` when it's crashing, or some value might be a good help (for you too).

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini error added

Comment: Add all logs, not just the stack trace

Comment: The error is pretty clear, please read the message closely: *Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x7fff86d79440) to 'NSString'* means that the value for key `image` is a number (`Int`, `Bool` or `Double`)

Comment: @vadian yes it is int, I am using number to index the images and by image number I get a full link of it, I added the full code now

Comment: If you know that the value is a number why do you cast it to `String`? Force downcast to a mismatched type causes a crash.

Comment: @vadian actually this is an old code I used before on IOS9 but now on ios14 it is not working properly, and if I cast it as int I will end up with Value of type 'Int' has no member 'addingPercentEncoding' on this line Value of type 'Int' has no member 'addingPercentEncoding'

Comment: The code crashes also in IOS 9 if the backend sends the same data.

Comment: Stop with "casting". If the response is a `Int` and you want a `String`, you don't cast, you transform (init method, etc.) since a cast will always fail. Now, if sometimes the value is a String and sometimes an Int, you have to test it. But if it's an Int, let's say `392`, how is that supposed to be transformed into a URL ? It's `http://392.png`? Doesn't make sense to me. Clarify your API response beforehand.